# I AM GETTING THIS ERROR WHEN I TRIED TO INSTALL REACT-NATIVE EXPO CLI

Tags: react-native, installation, expo

npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

Answer (score 1):

These are only warnings about certain versions of packages, there are only errors that can block the installation.